# Problems after boot 18.04 LTS can't open LibreOffice

Tags: 18.04

After successfully installed 18.04 LTS in an old laptop, I decided to make the same in mine.
Not quite the same, several bugs I've encounter;
- the desktop doesn't appear with the icons on the background. Just the background picture.
- I can't run LibreOffice, I'm going to try to install the version 6.1
Thanks for your possible help.